# DELETE SQL: how delete only one value at a time

Tags: oracle, unique, sql-delete

i have this sql string

```
"DELETE FROM project.cart WHERE isbn = ?";
```

If the table there are many isbn same, I can delete a single isbn every time I click on jbutton?

PS: isbn = ? ->  takes its value from a txfield and it all works, but if there are equal isbn delete them all of course.

thanks to all.

Comment: Is there a unique key in the table containing the ISBN numbers? If there is, you can read the ISBN and keys with a select statement and then delete where key = one of the keys you found.

Comment: @SimonElliott yes It was a primary key. but I did not need. and I disabled in the Oracle database. And 'possible to eliminate isbn one at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle inserts a hidden column called ROWNUM

```
DELETE FROM project.cart WHERE isbn = ? and ROWNUM=1;
```